"Genus theory" for elliptic curve $L$-functions
Let $d$ be a positive integer, so that $-d$ is a fundamental discriminant. This means that $d$ is square-free at odd primes and $\nu_2(d) \in \{0, 2, 3\}$. Further, if $\nu_2(d) > 0$ then $-d 2^{-\nu_2(d)} \equiv -1 \pmod{4}$. Let $h(-d)$ be the class number of the quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$. Dirichlet's class number formula asserts that
$$\displaystyle \frac{\pi h(-d)}{\sqrt{d}} = L(1, \chi_{-d}), d > 4$$
where $\chi_{-d}$ is the field character of $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$. A fundamental problem in number theory is to obtain an effective lower bound for $h(-d)$. By the class number formula above, this is equivalent to estimating $L(1,\chi_{-d})$ from below.
The term $L(1, \chi_{-d})$ is the residue of the Dedekind zeta function
$$\displaystyle \zeta_K(s) = \zeta(s) L(s, \chi_{-d}) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{v_n}{n^s}.$$
In turn, the coefficients $v_n$ of the Dedekind zeta function counts the number of integral ideals in $\mathcal{O}_K$ having norm equal to $n$.
Recall Gauss's genus theory for quadratic fields. This in particular gives a canonical construction of the 2-part of the ideal class group $\text{Cl}(-d)$. If $\chi$ is a class group character corresponding to 2-torsion, then the class group $L$-function of $\chi$ satisfies
$$\displaystyle L(s,\chi) = L(s, \chi_{d_1}) L(s, \chi_{d_2})$$
for some $d_1, d_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $d_1 d_2 = -d$ and both $d_1, d_2$ are fundamental discriminants. Then put
$$\zeta_{K}^\ast(s) = \sum_{-d_1 d_2 = d} L(s, \chi_{d_1}) L(s, \chi_{d_2}) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{v_n^\ast}{n^s}$$
where the sum runs over factorizations into fundamental discriminants. Then the coefficients $v_n^\ast$ satisfies
$$\displaystyle v_n^\ast = v_n \prod_{p | d} (1 + \chi_p(n)).$$
In other words, $v_n^\ast 2^{-\omega(d)}$ is the number of ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$ having norm equal to $n$ and in the principal genus.
Returning to the problem mentioned at the beginning of the post, the most remarkable progress towards an effective lower bound for $h(-d)$ and has in essence reduced the problem of enumerating imaginary quadratic fields of bounded class number to a finite computation, is a remarkable theorem due to Goldfeld and Gross-Zagier. To summarize, one finds an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$ which has analytic rank at least $3$. Then one constructs the $L$-function
$$\displaystyle L_{E/K}(s) = L_E(s) L_E(s, \chi_{-d})$$
and exploits the Deuring-Heilbronn phenomenon. The magic here is that the high-vanishing of $L_E(s)$ at $s = 1$ is independent of $L(1, \chi_{-d})$, so one dodges the question as to whether $L(s, \chi_{-d})$ has a Siegel zero. Of course, this is somewhat of a coincidence so this only allows one to prove that $h(-d) \geq c_\varepsilon (\log d)^{1 - \varepsilon}$, but the benefit is that this constant is effectively computable.
If one views $L_{E/K}(s)$ as an analogue of the Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_K(s)$, then I wonder what is the interpretation for the analogue of $\zeta_K^\ast(s)$, namely
$$\displaystyle L_{E/K}^\ast(s) = \sum_{d_1 d_2 = -d} L_E(s, \chi_{d_1}) L_E(s, \chi_{d_2}).$$
Note that for the coefficients $v_n$ and $v_n^\ast 2^{-\omega(d)}$, we have equality if $n$ is the norm of an ideal in the principal genus, otherwise $v_n^\ast = 0$. Further, $v_n, v_n^\ast \geq 0$ for all $n$. In that sense, $\zeta_K^\ast(s)$ is a "smaller" $L$-function than $\zeta_K(s)$. Furthermore, since the other summands in the definition of $\zeta_K^\ast(s)$ are holomorphic, $\zeta_K^\ast$ has a simple pole at $s = 1$.
My questions are:

What algebraic interpretation is there for the $L$-function $L_{E/K}^\ast(s)$?

What can one say about the order of vanishing of $L_{E/K}^\ast(s)$ compared to that of $L_{E/K}(s)$?



In the first display, the factor $2\pi$ should be $\pi$. This is because there is also the number of roots of unity, $w=2$, in the denominator. Also, the second sentence is not precise, it is not a correct characterization of negative fundamental discriminants.

Thanks, I fixed both issues.
